# How to locale the level or floor of the object in autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am getting the dbid of object and using the dbid I thought I would get the level of object from the properties which is defined as Layer but unfortunately few of my object does not have layer defined so is there any other way round where I can identify the level or floor where the object is present ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is RVT generated by Revit 2018 and later, you can get Level data and `dbIds` of the level occluder (e.g. floor, ceilings) by reading the [AecModelData](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api). Once you have AecModelData loaded, then you can take advantage of [Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-revit-levels-and-2d-minimap-your-3d) to get z ranges of each level.

```
const floorData viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Aec.LevelsExtension').floorSelector.floorData;

const currentLevel = floorData[0];
const currentLevelZmin = currentLevel.zMin;
const currentLevelZmax = currentLevel.zMax;
```

Afterward, compare the z value of the object you want with the level ranges to check if it's inside the level.

```
const minZ = currentLevel.zMin;
const maxZ = currentLevel.zMax;

let nodeBox = new Float32Array(6);
instanceTree.getNodeBox(dbId, nodeBox);

const nodeBoxMinZ = nodeBox[2];
const nodeBoxMaxZ = nodeBox[5];

let insideLevel = false;

if ((nodeBoxMinZ >= minZ && nodeBoxMinZ <= maxZ) ||
    (nodeBoxMaxZ >= minZ && nodeBoxMaxZ <= maxZ) ||
    (nodeBoxMinZ <= minZ && nodeBoxMaxZ >= maxZ)) {

    insideLevel = true;
}

if( insideLevel ) {
  // Do someting
}
```

BTW, if you load [Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-revit-levels-and-2d-minimap-your-3d) with the `ifcLevelsEnabled: true`, then this extension works for the IFC model, too. It will rebuild floor data for the IFC model on-the-fly.

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension', {ifcLevelsEnabled: true});
```

Comment: with new update I have replace   instanceTree.getNodeBox(dbId, nodeBox);
to
viewer.model.getInstanceTree().getNodeBox(10130, nodeBox);  for getting bounds but it returns me empty value

Comment: I did this  let nodeBox = new Float32Array(6);
                it.enumNodeChildren(it.getRootId(), function (dbId) {
                    console.log("Node ID" + dbId);
                    it.getNodeBox(dbId, nodeBox);
                }, true);

Comment: Hi Eason Kang, what if the model is not Revit model ? can I make a level of the building ?

Comment: Hi Surya, note sure what your source model format is, but here are two blogs that might help https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-i-nwc and https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-ii-ifc